# Could Someone explain me tihs SQL query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT carrier, id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights f
        WHERE f.id < flights.id
          AND f.carrier=flights.carrier) + 1 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights;
```

Guys I can't get this query, could someone explain me that what this is doing?

Comment: The sub-query counts the number of previous flights with the same carrier, plus 1.

Comment: It is called a `scalar subquery`, it yields **exactly one**  value for each tuple in the outer query.

Comment: @jarlh it is correlated subquery isnot it??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, it's correlated since it has an outer table condition.

Answer (score 1):

Let's alias tables for better understanding :

```
SELECT carrier, id,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights f1
    WHERE f1.id < f2.id
      AND f1.carrier=f2.carrier) + 1 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights f2;
```

What the outer query on the `f2` table does is, for each flight, it gets the `id`, the `carrier`, and the `flight_sequence_number`. The `flight_sequence_number` is computed by the inner query on `f1` by counting all occurences of flight that happened before the current flight (with the clause `f1.id < f2.id`) and that had the same `carrier` (with the clause `f1.carrier=f2.carrier`) and adds one, because the current flight won't be in the count.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is getting the Last ID from a specific Carrier and sum 1. It will get the next ID from the Carrier

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT f.carrier, f.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM flights f2
        WHERE f2.id < f.id AND
              f2.carrier = f.carrier
       ) as flight_sequence_number
FROM flights f;
```

I've rearranged things a little bit for clarity.

What does this do?  For each row in `flights` it is counting the number of `id`s strictly less than the `id` on the row and then adding `1`.

In simpler terms, it is enumerating the rows for each carrier.  This logic would more typically be written using window functions:

```
select f.*,
       rank() over (partition by f.carrier order by f.id) as flight_sequence_number
from flights f;
```

Under the (very reasonable) assumption that `id` is unique in the table, this would more colloquially be written using `row_number()`:

```
select f.*,
       row_number() over (partition by f.carrier order by f.id) as flight_sequence_number
from flights f;
```